# Existence of subgraphs when given its degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

For a given simple graph $G$ with $n$ vertices $v_1,v_2,\dots v_n$, the corresponding degree sequence is $d_1,d_2,\cdots,d_n$. My qusetion is:

> How to determine whether there exist subgraphs in $G$ such that it has the degree sequence of $d_1',d_2'\cdots,d_n'$ (where $d_i'\le d_i$)? If exist, how to get it?

(This is an extension of the question at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991607/existence-of-graphs-when-given-the-degrees-of-all-vertices).)

Comment: A quite related question is posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379153/simple-graphs-with-prescribed-degrees-as-disjoint-union-of-simple-subgraphs-with).

Comment: For this interested in this from a Theoretical CS point-of-view, the paper "Another look at the degree constrained subgraph problem" by Yossi Shiloach gives an polynomial-time algorithm for a generalization of this problem. 

I came across this question while I was searching for something related. What if we are instead ask if there is a subgraph with some given unordered degree sequence? It turns out that this problem is quite difficult; you can give have the input degree sequence to contain $k$ occurrences of $k$ and the rest 0. This is then basically the CLIQUE$_k$ problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ have vertices $v_1,\dots,v_n$.  Let $Z(G)$ denote the convex
hull in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of all *ordered* degree sequences
$(\deg(v_1),\dots ,\deg(v_n))$ of subgraphs of $G$. One way of stating
the well-known Erdős-Gallai characterization of degree sequences of
spanning subgraphs of the complete graph $K_n$ is that every integer
point in $Z(G)$ with even coordinate sum is a degree sequence of a
spanning subgraph of $K_n$. We can then ask for what other graphs $G$
is this statement true. A complete characterization is due to
Fulkerson, Hoffman, and McAndrew, Some properties of graphs with
multiple edges, *Canad. J. Math.* **17** (1965), 166-177, namely, no
induced subgraph of $G$ consists of two vertex-disjoint odd cycles
(with no other edges). Equivalently, every induced subgraph of $G$ has
at most one nonbipartite component.