# Simple graphs with prescribed degrees as disjoint union of simple subgraphs with prescribed degrees

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, random-graphs, subgraph, degree-sequence

Consider a set $V$ of $n$ vertices, and three degree sequences $a_i$, $b_i$ and $c_i$ such that $c_i = a_i+b_i$, $i=1..n$.

Assume these degree sequences are graphical: there exist *simple* graphs (no loop, no multiple edge) with degree sequence $a_i$, $b_i$, and $c_i$.

**Does this imply that there exists a *simple* graph $G_c=(V,E_c)$ with degree sequence $c_i$ being the *disjoint* union of two graphs $G_a = (V,E_a)$ and $G_b = (V,E_b)$ with degree sequence $a_i$ and $b_i$, respectively?**

Remarks:

- Disjoint union means here that $E_a \cup E_b = E_c$ and $E_a \cap E_b = \emptyset$; $E_a$ and $E_b$ form a *partition* of $E_c$.
- Since $a_i$ and $b_i$ are graphical, there exists simple graphs with these degree sequences. However, they may contain the same edges and so their union is not a simple graph with degree sequence $c_i$

Subsidiary questions:

- If such graphs do exist, how to build them?
- How to sample the two subgraphs uniformly at random?

Comment: could be of use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question is ***No***.

Let us assume $V = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and consider degree sequences $a = [3,2,2,1,0,0]$, $b = [1,0,0,3,2,2]$ and $c = a+b = [4,2,2,4,2,2]$.

The only simple graph with degree sequence $a$ is given by $1-2$, $1-3$, $1-4$, and $2-3$. Similarly, the only one with degree sequence $b$ is given by $4-1$, $4-5$, $4-6$, and $5-6$. In the union of these two graphs, the edge between $4$ and $1$ appears twice, making it a multi-graph.

However, $c$ is graphical: a simple graph with degree sequence $c$ is given by $1-2$, $1-3$, $1-5$, $1-6$, $4-2$, $4-3$, $4-5$, $4-6$.

Thus, **we have three graphical degree sequences $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $c=a+b$ but no simple graph with degree sequence $c$ is the disjoint union of a simple graph with degree sequence $a$ and a simple graph with degree sequence $b$**.

Answer (score 2):

I think your property is true and can be shown recursively depending on the size $n$ of the graph.

### Existence

For $n=2$ well one of the sequences has to be (0,0), so the other one is equal to $c$: it works just fine.

Now suppose that works for any valid sequence of length $n-1$ for some integer $n>2$. Take valid degree sequences $a$, $b$, $c$ of size $n$. Build any simple graph $G=(V,E)$ following sequence $c$.

Remove whichever node $u$ and its adjacent edges $U$. It will change the degree distrubution of its neighbours $N_u$ in the remaining graph. Define sequences $c'$, $a'$ and $b'$, copies of $c$, $a$ and $b$ except:
$$\forall v\in N_u, c'_v=c_v-1$$
$$\forall v\in N_u\text{ st }a_v>0, a'_v=a_v-1 $$
$$\forall v\in N_u\text{ st }a_v=0, b'_v=b_v-1 $$

The edges in $U$ can be separated in $E_a$ and $E_b$ depending on whether they impact distribution $a'$ or $b'$:
$$E_a=\{(u,v)\in U \:|\: a_v>0\}$$
$$E_b=\{(u,v)\in U \:|\: a_v=0\}$$

*By construction, we have $\forall v\in V, c'_v=a'_v+b'_v$, and $a',b',c'$ are valid sequences of size $n-1$.* **This is not necessarily true: the sequences may not be valid, so the recursion is wrong.**

By assumption, we can build a graph $G'=(V',E')$ such that:

- $V'=V\backslash\{u\}$
- $E'=E'_a\cup E'_b$ and $E'_a\cap E'_b=\emptyset$
- $G'$ follows distribution $c'$, $G'_a=(V',E'_a)$ follows distribution $a'$ and $G'_b=(V',E'_b)$ follows distribution $b'$

Finally, you add the node $u$ and its former edges to obtain the graph $G^*=(V,E'\cup U)$. The partition of edges is $E_a^*=E_a\cup E'_a$ and $E_b^*=E_b\cup E'_b$, which satisfies all the properties.

So this decomposition exists for distributions of size $n$.

### Construction

This recursion provides a constructive process. If distributions of size $n$ are given, assuming they are valid, you can select a random node to remove, apply the procedure on the remaining graph, and then add the extra edges.

Note that the above definition of $E_a$ and $E_b$ is not symmetrical: it would be more balanced to choose at random if an edge of $U$ is affected to $E_a$ or $E_b$.

If $u$ is also chosen at random, and the case $n=2$ forces uniformly $a=c$ or $b=c$, then it may be considered as "uniform". However in my opinion, this concept needs to be clearly defined. Moreover, the recursion may not yield all the possible constructions.

Cheers!

Comment: I think it does not work. What if you remove a node $u$ such that $b_u>0$, but always fall in the case $a_v>0$?

For example, consider $a=[1,1,1,1]$, $b=[0,1,1,0]$, $c=[1,2,2,1]$ and take $G=(\{1,2,3,4\},\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\})$.
Remove node $u=2$, you then obtain: $a'=[0,DEL,0,1]$, $b'=[0,DEL,1,0]$, $c'=[0,DEL,1,1]$.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Thank you very much, Vendec, nice approach. But I fear @maxdan94 is right with his counter-example, thanks Max! This is a counter-example of the construction proposed by Vendec, though, not a counter-example of the initial claim, so the question remains open.

Comment: Indeed, the counter example shows that the sequences a' and b' may not be valid: i edited my post to stress this flaw! cheers

Answer (score 0):

*The proof is not correct, bits of text in italic below correspond to the parts of the proof which are flawed.*

I think that the property is true, and that we can build a solution and then a random sample of such graphs.

Here is a scheme of proof. It needs a little more formalization, though I think there are enough elements to assess if it works or not.

**Proof of existence and construction process**

- Finding adequate $G_a=(V,E_a)$ and $G_b=(V,E_b)$ is equivalent to color the edges of a realization of $c$, so that an edge is either red (belongs to $E_a$) or blue (belongs to $E_b$), I will use this lexicon in the following,
- let $G_c=(V,E)$ be any realization of sequence $c$ (for example achieved using a Havel-Hakimi process),
- the general idea is, starting from $G_c$ to color edges in red following a process similar to Havel-Hakimi process based on sequence $a$, either the edge to color already exists in $G_c$ and this is fine, or it doesn't and in this case we create the edge by swapping edges,
- precisely, let us suppose that nodes are relabeled $1, 2, \ldots ,n$  so that $a$ is ordered in a decreasing order: $ a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \ldots \geq a_n $
- according to Havel-Hakimi, we should color edges $ (1,2) $, $(1,3)$ , ... , $(1,a_1+1)$ (if these edges do not exist we will modify the graph without changing its degree sequence $c$, as explained later), when this is done the remaining degree sequence of $a$ is reordered and we distribute the remaining highest degree node over the other highest degree nodes and so on until sequence $a$ is realized by $ G_a=(V,E_a)$
- when trying to color an edge $(u,v)$, one of two things are possible:

  - either $ (u,v) $ exists in the graph then the edge is colored in red,
  - or it doesn't, so $u$ is related to another node $x$ by an uncolored edge and so is $v$ to $y$, so we can swap these edges by connecting $u$ to $v$ and $x$ to $y$,

    - there are a few special cases to handle: i) if $ (x,y) $ already exists (which would lead to a multi-edge) and ii) if $x=y$ (which would lead to a self-loop)
    - i) if $ (x,y) $ already exists and is red, we can simply color $(u,x)$  and $ (v,y) $ in red and turn back $ (x,y) $ uncolored, we have strictly decreased $a$ sequence and we carry on the process,
    - *if $ (x,y) $ already exists and is uncolored, note that edges which will belong to $E_b$ are uncolored at this stage, so we know that there is another uncolored edge $ (x',y') $ in the graph, otherwise sequence $b$ is $ (2,2) $ which is not a valid sequence, here it can be objected that we can have $ x' = x $ (or similarly $ y' = y$) but we would go back to a similar problem: it leads to a sequence (3,2,1) which is not valid,*
    - ii) *if $x=y$, we can make a similar argument: there must be an uncolored edge  $ (x',y') $ elsewhere in the graph with both $ x \neq x'$ and $ x \neq y'$ for sequence $b$ to be valid, then we can swap $(u,x)$ and $ (x',y') $ to create $ (u,x') $ and $(x,y')$ and it is possible to swap again to create $ (u,v) $ and $ (x,x') $*
  - *So in all cases, we can always find either a swap sequence or a recoloring sequence which allows to continue the process until we have completed the red-coloration of edges.*

*In the end, the set of red edges is $E_a$ and the remaining uncolored edges of the modified graph can be colored in blue as they satisfy $ \forall i$, $ c_i = a_i + b_i $ (we didn't change the degree of any node in the original graph, and we colored exactly $a_i$ edges incident to node $c_i$)*.

**Sampling**

For this part, I think that the following process achieves a uniform random sampling:

- starting from the 2-color graph constructed above, select any edge randomly
- depending on its color, select any edge of the same color, swap their ends as long as it doesn't create a loop or a multi-edge of this color, if it does, we keep the current configuration,
- iterate this process until we reach the steady state of this Markov process
- note that this process can produce 2-edges as we may get two nodes connected simultaneously by a blue edge and a red edge

  - if there is one or more 2-edge, we discard the graph obtained as it is not a valid realization of $c$, and restart the process,
  - if the final graph doesn't have 2-edge, the 2-colored graph is a valid realization of $G_c$ which edge-coloring corresponds to a valid realization of $b$ and $b$ is added to the sample.

Such a process is very similar to sampling graphs with a given degree sequence with a swap process, which has been largely discussed in the literature (I like [this article](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.72.056708) where it is called "switching-and-holding").

Again, it deserves a formal proof, but I have good confidence that this process achieves detailed balance which leads to a uniform sample.

Comment: Thank you, @Alt-Tab, this approach is very interesting too, although it seems to me that it is flawed. In particular, I am unsure point (i) is always possible.

Comment: I think you are right @MatthieuLatapy and your counter-example indeed defaults point (i) in my attempt of a proof: you may not find any available edge for swap and still have a valid $b$
sequence, I will indicate the parts of the text which are not correct. An interesting question would be to investigate if we can find families of sequences for which this process (or another) works.